# Brew stand recommendations

Tags: equipment, all-grain, large-batch

My buddy and I are looking to upgrade to a 20 gallon brew stand, and I'm looking for recommendations between buying a full setup, which brand, or making one ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing a lot of research for my own purposes.

Brutus 10 is the gold standard of making your own.
http://homebrewacademy.com/brutus-10-build

Or, if you don't want to weld, which is the one I'm probably going to do.
http://www.aleiens.com/profiles/blogs/wallace-the-weldless-brew

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the 13 gallon Braumeister50 (50 litres).

Combined with it I also use a 15 gallon (70 litre) saucepan (on a gas ring) that I mashout into for the boil/chill cycle which allows me to reload the BM50 for another mash giving me 26 gallons of liquid paradise in a nine-hour brewday.

I have yet to have a problem with it after some 30 or so brews.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have a More Beer Tippy system that I love. Easy to clean, brews with consistency once you figure out how to use it well and has automation for heating elements and thermostats that makes brewing fun. I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

i pieced my home 20 gallon system together i used angle iron from home depot  and used high temp paint on it.  march pumps and rims system that i built from scratch. its much more fulfilling to do it your self.

Comment: Do you have any plans? What did the materials end up costing you?

Comment: i think the angle iron cost me something like a 100 bucks. i dont have any plans i built it to fit my pot, mash, and htl.    there is http://www.homebrewtalk.com  also  http://www.homebrewersassociation.org/   they will be both great resources.   it just depends  every one is going to have a different idea on  how to do it. so build it to be functional for you